# Can I hardcode my StoryBoard?

Tags: xcode, model-view-controller

I'm new to iOS developing and xCode from WPF C# (where I almost never drag and drop but hard code my "view"). In xCode 4.2, does all the **view** in MVC contains in the **MainStoryBoard.storyboard**? Can I hardcode my view (or, can I hardcode my storyboard or view its source code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an entire app without touching interface builder or storyboards. But I'd strongly recommend actually using them instead - if you're writing an iOS app, write an iOS app, don't try and crowbar in practices from a different framework.